# OutOfMemoryException when calling SetSource for BitmapImage in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am basically trying to convert a GIF image to a PNG image using the ImageTools library in WP7.

```
byte[] gifBytes = // GIF image bytes from the web

ImageTools.IO.Decoders.AddDecoder<GifDecoder>();
ImageTools.IO.Encoders.AddEncoder<PngEncoder>();
ImageTools.IO.Png.PngEncoder enc = new PngEncoder();

ExtendedImage gifImage = new ExtendedImage();
gifImage.SetSource(new MemoryStream(gifBytes));                

MemoryStream pngBytes = new MemoryStream();
enc.Encode(gifImage, pngBytes);

BitmapImage pngImage = new BitmapImage(); 
pngImage.SetSource(pngBytes);
```

As soon as I call `pngImage.SetSource(pngBytes)` I get `OutOfMemoryException`.

Maybe there's something else I don't grock here since the debugger also shows that gifImage is 0x0 after I called `gifImage.SetSource(new MemoryStream(gifBytes))`. For what's its worth, I've checked that `gifBytes[]` contains valid GIF bytes...

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image you are working with?

Comment: I would not know that in advance. I basically have a set of bytes that I know are a GIF image. Out of curiosity, where would this information be needed in this context? Do I need to know that in order to create an ExtendedImage (that is the GIF)?

Comment: Oh - but for this particular case that I now have, the image is 600px × 205px.

Comment: Is that an animated gif? When dealing with animated gif, ImageTools internally stores the uncompressed bitmap representation of the gif (a bitmap per frame, 4 bytes per pixel). In this case, that makes 600 * 205 * 4 = 492 ko per frame. Depending on the number of frames on the gif, it can grow *really* fast.

Comment: Nope, it's not an animated Gif. The Gif byte array is 42919 bytes long. Doesn't sound too big to me which leads me to believe that there must be something else going on that I don't understand...

Comment: Then I believe the best is to trace the memory consumption after each line to understand which instruction makes the memory skyrocket. Though it's probably the last line. ImageTools isn't very error tolerant, I would not be surprised that a malformed gif causes an infinite loop somewhere. The ImageTool source code is available, you can download it, reference the project rather than the binary dll, then debug step by step to understand where it crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure if it helps or not, but before SetSource() the mem consuption is 9723904 bytes (according to DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage) and after 9764864 bytes when I print the same info in the catch section. It's maybe also worth noting that the exception comes from BitmapImage and not ImageTools library. But of course maybe the ImageTools library created some data the BitmapImage cannot grasp and, for whatever reason, thorws the OutofMemoryException.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the issue is with the ImageTools library that I am using. Not sure how to 100% confirm this, but it seems that if ImageTools encodes faulty image bytes that I try to set as source for the BitmapImage, the BitmapImage will throw an OutOfMemoryException.

So I would call this a bug in both ImageTools library for not being able to encode a perfectly good Gif image to PNG format but also in BitmapImage for throwing the wrong exception in this case.